# Layer not loading correctly after table join

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am attempting to perform a table join from a plug-in/outside of the built-in Python console. This is QGIS 3.16.1 and Python 3.7. I want to join two vector point layers, which have all points in exactly the same places. This is my code for the join:

```
# Create layers for output files
vectorpoint_filled_one = QgsVectorLayer(outputfile, '', 'ogr')
vectorpoint_filled_two = QgsVectorLayer(outputfile_two, 'final', 'ogr')

# Join tables
join_info = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
join_info.setJoinLayer(vectorpoint_filled_one)
join_info.setJoinFieldName('field1')
join_info.setTargetFieldName('field1')
join_info.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
join_info.setJoinFieldNamesBlockList(['geom_X', 'geom_Y'])
vectorpoint_filled_two.addJoin(join_info)

# add to map canvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vectorpoint_filled_two) #loads version from before table join
```

For some reason, the loaded map is `vectorpoint_filled_two` **before** the table join. However, when I also load `vectorpoint_filled_one`, the `vectorpoint_filled_two` is loaded (correctly) after the table join:

```
# Create layers for output files
vectorpoint_filled_one = QgsVectorLayer(outputfile, '', 'ogr')
vectorpoint_filled_two = QgsVectorLayer(outputfile_two, 'final', 'ogr') 

# Join tables - add if statement to skip for no vector layers or no raster layers
join_info = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
join_info.setJoinLayer(vectorpoint_filled_one)
join_info.setJoinFieldName('field1')
join_info.setTargetFieldName('field1')
join_info.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
join_info.setJoinFieldNamesBlockList(['geom_X', 'geom_Y'])
vectorpoint_filled_two.addJoin(join_info)

# add to map canvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vectorpoint_filled_one)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vectorpoint_filled_two) #now loads correctly
```

This works, but I don't want to load `vectorpoint_filled_one`, as it is otherwise useless. I have tried various manners of reloading and updating `vectorpoint_filled_two` after the table join (`startEditing()` + `commitChanges()`,  `reload()`), but it keeps loading the older version. I have also tried removing `vectorpoint_filled_one` **after** `vectorpoint_filled_two` is added to the map, but this will also result in the join missing from the loaded layer. Since the second version does work and `addJoin` returns `True`, I know the table join and previous code creating the layers are correct.

How do I load the correct version of `vectorpoint_filled_two` without also loading the other layer?